# converting sql to linq woes

Tags: linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

At my job our main application was written long ago before n-tier was really a thing, ergo - it has tons and tons of business logic begin handled in stored procs and such.

So we have finally decided to bite the bullet and make it not suck so bad.  I have been tasked with converting a 900+ line sql script to a .NET exe, which I am doing in C#/Linq.  Problem is...for the last 5-6 years at another job, I had been doing Linq exclusively, so my SQL has gotten somewhat rusty, and some of thing I am converting I have never tried to do before in Linq, so I'm hitting some roadblocks.

Anyway, enough whining.

I'm having trouble with the following sql statement, I think due to the fact that he is joining on a temp table and a derived table.  Here's the SQL:

```
insert into #processedBatchesPurgeList
    select d.pricebatchdetailid
    from pricebatchheader h (nolock)
    join pricebatchstatus pbs (nolock) on h.pricebatchstatusid = pbs.pricebatchstatusid
    join pricebatchdetail d (nolock) on h.pricebatchheaderid = d.pricebatchheaderid
    join 
    (   -- Grab most recent REG.
        select
            item_key 
            ,store_no
            ,pricebatchdetailid = max(pricebatchdetailid)
        from pricebatchdetail _pbd (nolock)
        join pricechgtype pct (nolock) on _pbd.pricechgtypeid = pct.pricechgtypeid
        where
            lower(rtrim(ltrim(pct.pricechgtypedesc))) = 'reg'
            and expired = 0
        group by item_key, store_no
    ) dreg
        on d.item_key = dreg.item_key
        and d.store_no = dreg.store_no
    where
        d.pricebatchdetailid < dreg.pricebatchdetailid -- Make sure PBD is not most recent REG.
        and h.processeddate < @processedBatchesPurgeDateLimit
        and lower(rtrim(ltrim(pbs.pricebatchstatusdesc))) = 'processed' -- Pushed/processed batches only.
```

So that's raising an overall question first:  how to handle temp tables in Linq?  This script uses about 10 of them.  I currently have them as List.  The problem is, if I try to .Join() on one in a query, I get the "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." error.

I was able to get the join to the derived table to work using 2 queries, just so a single one wouldn't get nightmarishly long:

```
var dreg = (from _pbd in db.PriceBatchDetails.Where(pbd => pbd.Expired == false && pbd.PriceChgType.PriceChgTypeDesc.ToLower().Trim() == "reg")
                    group _pbd by new { _pbd.Item_Key, _pbd.Store_No } into _pbds
                    select new 
                    {
                        Item_Key = _pbds.Key.Item_Key,
                        Store_No = _pbds.Key.Store_No,
                        PriceBatchDetailID = _pbds.Max(pbdet => pbdet.PriceBatchDetailID)
                    });

        var query = (from h in db.PriceBatchHeaders.Where(pbh => pbh.ProcessedDate < processedBatchesPurgeDateLimit)
                    join pbs in db.PriceBatchStatus on h.PriceBatchStatusID equals pbs.PriceBatchStatusID
                    join d in db.PriceBatchDetails on h.PriceBatchHeaderID equals d.PriceBatchHeaderID
                    join dr in dreg on new { d.Item_Key, d.Store_No } equals new { dr.Item_Key, dr.Store_No }
                    where d.PriceBatchDetailID < dr.PriceBatchDetailID
                    && pbs.PriceBatchStatusDesc.ToLower().Trim() == "processed"
                    select d.PriceBatchDetailID);
```

So that query gives the expected results, which I am holding in a List, but then I need to join the results of that query to another one selected from the database, which is leading me back to the aforementioned "Local sequence cannot be used..." error.

That query is this:

```
insert into #pbhArchiveFullListSaved
    select h.pricebatchheaderid
    from pricebatchheader h (nolock)
        join pricebatchdetail d (nolock)
            on h.pricebatchheaderid = d.pricebatchheaderid
        join #processedBatchesPurgeList dlist
            on d.pricebatchdetailid = dlist.pricebatchdetailid -- PBH list is restricted to PBD purge list rows that have PBH references.
    group by h.pricebatchheaderid
```

The join there on #processedBatchesPurgeList is the problem I am running into.

So uh...help?  I have never written SQL like this, and certainly never tried to convert it to Linq.

Comment: If your sql uses many temp tables, and you can't refactor them away, a stored proc is probably the best option.

Comment: 2nd that.  If that is working it looks like pretty clean TSQL.  #processedBatchesPurgeList is probably expensive and it gets materialized so it is not reevaluated multiple times in that join later.  Those (nolock) are not there by accident.   Before you go too far compare the performance of the LINQ to the TSQL.

Comment: I would also agree that you quite possibly are wasting your time converting something that works, however cool LINQ is! What was the reason for the rewrite of this script? Why not just fire the sql script from the exe? You know it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah that's eventually what it turned into.  Well, not firing the sql directly from an exe, but wrapping the script in a stored proc and calling that.  Whole project was due to SOX compliance, since dba's executing data changing scripts by hand is a no-no.  Weeeeee.  Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments above, this is no longer being rewritten as Linq.

Was hoping to get a performance improvement along with achieving better SOX compliance, which was the whole reason for the rewrite in the first place.

I'm happy with *just* satisfying the SOX compliance issues.

Thanks, everyone.